# I would like to split a huge file into many number of files with the header in all split files. Using python

Tags: python

```
"SURNAME","GIVENNAME","MIDDLENAME","UPIN","NAME","CODE"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770"
"ADU", "GOU","RAN", "3cxd", "GOU RAN", "0770
```

Let's suppose this is the format of the huge file and I would like to split into many number of files with specified size and in each file I need the header ("SURNAME","GIVENNAME","MIDDLENAME","UPIN","NAME","CODE") to be present.Thanks in advance.

---

```
import os
import sys

def getfilesize(filename):
   with open(filename,"rb") as fr:
       fr.seek(0,2) # move to end of the file
       size=fr.tell()
       print("getfilesize: size: %s" % size)
       return fr.tell()

def splitfile(filename, splitsize):
   # Open original file in read only mode
   if not os.path.isfile(filename):
       print("No such file as: \"%s\"" % filename)
       return

   filesize=getfilesize(filename)
   with open(filename,"rb") as fr:
    counter=1
    orginalfilename = filename.split(".")
    readlimit = 1000000 #read 5kb at a time
    n_splits = filesize//splitsize
    print("splitfile: No of splits required: %s" % str(n_splits))
    for i in range(n_splits+1):
        chunks_count = int(splitsize)//int(readlimit)
        data_5kb = fr.read(readlimit) # read
        # Create split files
        print("chunks_count: %d" % chunks_count)
        with open(orginalfilename[0]+"_{id}.".format(id=str(counter))+orginalfilename[1],"ab") as fw:
            fw.seek(0) 
            fw.truncate()# truncate original if present
            while data_5kb:                
                fw.write(data_5kb)
                if chunks_count:
                    chunks_count-=1
                    data_5kb = fr.read(readlimit)
                else: break            
        counter+=1 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   if len(sys.argv) < 3: print("Filename or splitsize not provided: Usage:     filesplit.py filename splitsizeinkb ")
   else:
       filesize = int(sys.argv[2]) * 1000 #make into kb
       filename = sys.argv[1]
       splitfile(filename, filesize)
```

This works fine but couldn't get the Headers and I'm sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Please post your attempt.  Also what kind of files are you splitting these into?  what is the criteria, can you provide samples?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Does it have to be in Python? Other methods may be significantly faster. Anyway, show us what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried this one and It works fine but I'm not getting the header

Comment: I will post my code and It works fine but I'm not able to get the headers in the files which I have split.

Comment: Sure @MoinuddinQuadri Thanks a ton , I'm new to this environment.

Comment: @AlexHall Unfortunately It has to be python :(. Thanks !

Comment: Hello @EoinS I have posted it but couldn't get the header. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
import os

maxlines = 1000  # how many lines did you want each new file to have?
infilepath = 'path/to/file'
with open(infilepath) as infile:
    dirpath = os.path.dirname(infilepath)
    fname = os.path.basename(infilepath)
    fname, ext = fname.rsplit('.',1)

    header = infile.readline()
    outfile = open(os.path.join(dirpath, "{}{}.{}".format(fname, 0, ext)), 'w')

    for i,line in enumerate(infile):
        if not i%maxlines:
            outfile.close()
            outfile = open(os.path.join(dirpath, "{}{}.{}".format(fname, i//maxlines, ext)), 'w')
            outfile.write(header)
        outfile.write(line)

    try: outfile.close()
    except: pass
```

Comment: Thanks inspectorG4dget but I'm getting error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Henry/Desktop/G_Scripts/Py/split_new.py", line 7, in <module>
    outfile.close()
NameError: name 'outfile' is not defined, I'm new to Stackoverflow and have basic knowledge of python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Henry/Desktop/G_Scripts/Py/split_new.py", line 7, in <module>
    outfile.close()
NameError: name 'outfile' is not defined

Comment: @GOU7HAM: oops! sorry about that. I've fixed it now

Comment: It works perfectly but I have a question if my file is ('new.txt') then all the output file names are ('new.txt0', 'new.txt1', 'new.txt2', 'new.txt3'....) and couldn't open these file unless if I use notepad++. Thanks a ton. Please suggest me.

Comment: and instead of having line numbers can we do it with size ? Let's suppose If I have a file size of 100MB and If I were to split with 10MB each. Please suggest me. Thanks @inspectorG4dget.

Comment: @GOU7HAM: I fixed the file naming issues. Given your data, splitting by lines should be somewhat equivalent to splitting by size

Comment: No worries I've figured it out for the file name extensions. I just want to know how to split it with the data size. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I have used pandas to split large files into smaller ones

```
import pandas as pd

infile = #path to your file

n=0
for chunk in pd.read_csv(infile, sep = ',', chunksize=1000000):
    data = chunk
    oPath = 'chunk_' +str(n)+'.csv'
    data.to_csv(oPath, sep=' ',index=False, header=true)
    n +=1
```

`chunksize` indicates how many lines you want in the output files .